# Sharepoint Workflow 2010 - Change the column hyperlink after the item added

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Using SharePoint 2010 Designer, I have a requirement to modify the list item hyperlink when a new list item created. I am calling the workflow when a new item created. I like to get the description value of hyperlink field.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the description of a `HyperLink` column in the following way.

[image]

Comment: Hi, We tried the same but we get didnt get any value. What will be the reason?

Comment: Does your hyperlink column contains any value Or show how did you try?

Comment: I showed how i tried

Comment: It seems ok. I will test and let you know